# How to clean the workspace in python?

Tags: python

After I import some functions from a module

```
>>> from math import pi, e, sin, cos
>>> dir()
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', 'cos', 'e', 'pi', 'sin']
```

Can I clean the workspace? I mean, other than manually like

```
>>> del pi, e, sin, cos
>>> dir()
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__']
```

Something like the matlab/octave `clear`?

Comment: Nope, there is no 'clear' command. Just restart the interactive interpreter.

Comment: Looking for `Cntrl + l` ?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Should I close or delete the question? Or you write the answer and I tag it like an answer? I looked for it but I did not find any information so I was not sure... Maybe nice to have the answer here?

Comment: @sebas It is a good question that others might wonder about. I know in R for example, there is also an easy way to interactively clear your environment from the REPL and given the way some people in data science are migrating from R to Python + pandas, that might be one of the first things they think about. Unless it is a duplicate, I would keep it for that reason. It would be nice to have an authoritative answer, even if that answer is just "no" (although I wouldn't be surprised if for at least some IDEs the answer is "yes" since an IDE is free to add functionality to its version of the REPL)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [IPython](https://ipython.org), which has a `%reset` command that does just that and it's overall a good tool if you want to use the interactive interpreter for doing complex stuff.