# How to make one script variable not affect/not transfer to the other script environment in Spyder

Tags: python, environment-variables, global-variables

I have been searching for an answer for awhile and I could not find, or I am not sure how to word it and I cannot find the correct question.

So I have 2 scripts. Let us say Script 1 and Script 2.
Script 1 is like below

```
x1 = 0
```

Script 2 is like below

```
x1 = 1
X2 = x1 + 0
```

But if I run Script 1 first and then run Script 2, then x2 would be 0...
If I run Script 2 to begin with, or if I close Spyder and then run Script 2 again, which is basically running Script 2 to begin with, then x2 = 1, just like I wanted.

How can I try to get rid of this "variable" transferring from one script to the other even if they get defined again?

I tried

```
globals().clear()
```

But it does not seem to do the trick.

Comment: I'm not familliar with Spyder but could you change the variable names? or prepend the variable with `script1_x1` and `script2_x2`, same variable names with a simple script as your example shouldn't be a problem with normal python but since I don't know Spyder maybe it does something weird that I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48038888) answer from a similar question can help you.

---

In case the link becomes inaccessible, it says :

> In Spyder, Do following steps
>
> Run Configuration per file...
>
> Clear all variables before execution [Select Checkbox]
>
> This actually clears variables from previous run of the file. Hope it
> helps.
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNUl9.jpg

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This should not happen. Anyway, you have several options, while the 3 one is my recomendation:

1. Remove directly the `x1` variable at the end of Script1:

```
del x1
```

2. Use [IPython](https://ipython.org/) interpreter as explained in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42722817/21233002
3. Spyder IDE has a preference configuration to save or remove variables. You have to go to `Tools` > `Preference` > `Run` > `General settings` and select the option `Remove all variables before execution`. This will do the trick. You can see it in the following image:

[See image with Spyder Preference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvDyW.png)